# In tensorflow Model class , how the call method works?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

in this code i understand , **init** is used for defining the layers and inside the call i can see the how the feedforward works .

1. i didnt understand how this call method working under the hood
2. is this equal to dunder call method  ?
3. is this a normal method like all ,should we need to call like --> instance.call() ?

```
class WideAndDeepModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units=30, activation="relu", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # needed to support naming the model
        self.norm_layer_wide = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
        self.norm_layer_deep = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
        self.hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
        self.hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
        self.main_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        self.aux_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        input_wide, input_deep = inputs
        norm_wide = self.norm_layer_wide(input_wide)
        norm_deep = self.norm_layer_deep(input_deep)
        hidden1 = self.hidden1(norm_deep)
        hidden2 = self.hidden2(hidden1)
        concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([norm_wide, hidden2])
        output = self.main_output(concat)
        aux_output = self.aux_output(hidden2)
        return output, aux_output

model = WideAndDeepModel(30, activation="relu", name="my_cool_model")
```

Please any one clarify or provide any sufficient source for understanding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at below link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#call

The initial states of model sets by **init** and other specifications of layers could be set by call() method which could be used in instances and subclasses.

In **init** you specify your layers and their propereties like the activation function of layer and number of nodes in each layer (unit argument). Then in call() method you specify the flow of layer that means output of which layer should be input of which one. As you see in below lines of your code:

```
hidden1 = self.hidden1(norm_deep)
hidden2 = self.hidden2(hidden1)
concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([norm_wide, hidden2])
```

you also specify the output in call(). Input defines the shape of your input layer.  for example, if you are working with images as input and you have 20 images of 30x30 pixels in RGB (3 channels), the shape of your input data is (20,30,30,3) and your input layer tensor could be defined like below:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(20,30,30,3))
```

of course the above is not your input shape, as you have in call() method: `input_wide, input_deep = inputs`

Comment: @Abolfazi could you please help me to understand when this call function invocation will happen ?

Comment: @MATHAN PRASANNA KUMAR S, I added more explanation to my answer. Please read my comment again.

Comment: at the last line in my code , instance is created for the class , at the time of creation only __init__ method will be called right ? , then i can compile the model and fit the model , but during these process how  the logic inside the call method is applied, normally in the functional api , at the time of model instance  the logic and layers is being passing as a inputs and outputs , please forgive me if am asking dumb question  i am new here

Comment: No, call() method is implemented as well, but when you want to build your model, you need to specify input shape. Unless your above code could not be built, using build() method. After specifying input shape, you can build your model and after that you can train your model with input data.

Comment: so model.call((x,y)), would it work fine ?

Comment: No, this is like __init__ and magic methods. It will be implemented when you insatiate a class inherited from tf.keras.Model. You can not call it like model.call((x,y)).

Comment: The actual method in tf.keras.Model class is __call__ magic method that makes instances callable. When you inherit from tf.keras.Model, you can write call() instead of __call__ magic method and this call() method will overwrite __call__ magic method in tf.keras.Model class.

Comment: ,Thank a lot sir , now i got some clarity .